# How to build Docker for VS 2019 solution?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-2019

I have a VS 2019 Solution with 2 projects: P1 (Standard lib) & P2 (ASP.NET Core exe).
P2 contains a Dockerfile.
I have copied the Docker file to up folder, tried to build the docker running the cmd :

```
>docker build -f Dockerfile ..
Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.056GB
Step 1/18 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
 ---> 5d7a95ed1660
Step 2/18 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 6e8271ae3df9
Step 3/18 : EXPOSE 80
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e45066aa184b
Step 4/18 : EXPOSE 443
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 0bbce5ed4c30
Step 5/18 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
 ---> 925a86b607a3
Step 6/18 : WORKDIR /src
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e4af901c8e34
Step 7/18 : COPY ["PropMan/PropMan.csproj", "PropMan/"]
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder808977273/PropMan/PropMan.csproj: no such file or directory
```

How to fix it?

The directory structure

```
-Solution dir
--ChartJs.Blazor project
---ChartJs.Blazor.csproj
---ChartJs.Blazor files
--PropMan project
---PropMan.csproj
---PropMan files
---Dockerfie (it was created here but later I moved it to solution folder)
-Dockerfie
```

The Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["PropMan/PropMan.csproj", "PropMan/"]
COPY ["ChartJs.Blazor/ChartJs.Blazor.csproj", "ChartJs.Blazor/"]
RUN dotnet restore "PropMan/PropMan.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/PropMan"
RUN dotnet build "PropMan.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "PropMan.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "PropMan.dll"]
```

Comment: *does* `PropMan/PropMan.csproj` exist?

Comment: Providing the Dockerfile would help a lot. Also the relevant directory structure (`tree` is a great tool)

Comment: The PropMan/PropMan.csproj exists, the VS builds the Solution ok.

Comment: According to your "directory structure", the csproj file is called "PropMan.Blazor.csproj". Are you sure "PropMan/PropMan.csproj", i.e. without "Blazor", exists?

Comment: Yes, it  was my copy/paste typo. It is Propman.csproj

Answer (score 0):

I need to go to the solution folder and run

> docker build -f PropMan/Dockerfile .

The Dockefile is in project folder.